# How to make modal visible by default when html page runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am creating a pop up div (modal) which will appear on screen by default. However I succeed to open it on button click but I want it open by default whenever I run the HTML page.
        Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h2>Modal Example</h2>
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where I am showing the modal using a button.In that I am using data-target property to invoke the modal. So how to do it without any click event?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **[`.modal('show')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods)** to show the model manually

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Pravan        now i want to show that modal as transperent.So that content on main page hidden behind modal also shown simultaneously any suggestion?

Comment: you can apply css `#myModal{ opacity : 0.5 ; }` ,  vary value in between 0 and 1

Comment: @Dhiraj : happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 8):

Add class in to html code , such that

```html
<div class="modal fade show d-block" id="newModal" role="dialog">
```

or you can call the following function when the page loads

```js
$('#newModal').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I've not enough reputation to add a comment. 
according to [bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options) component documentation, there's no need to pass any parameter to .modal() method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class `in` to `<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">`, such that

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="myModal" role="dialog">
```

or you can call the following function when the page loads

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

open modal at `document.ready()`

for eg.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    //open modal here
         $('#myModal').show();
      });
```